# Multiple Column headers lines in dxDBGrid in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, grid

Users are wanting a grid to have multiple lines in the column header, and I am not finding a solution.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the HeaderMaxLineCount property of the TdxDBGridColumn?

Comment: ahh, never saw that. I assume it will work, haven't got to try it out yet, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Additional information:

When you use the **cxGrid** component from devexpress you have to set the HeaderAutoHeight property to true (of cxGridDBTableView).